# Error MSB4064: The "AllowUnsecureUrls" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task

Tags: android, xamarin

So, I am getting this error on building Android Release. On debug things are fine. It wont even clean the solution.
Things were fine and now after updating to latest Xamarin.
This is what my Droid project top few lines look like

````
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.6.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.6.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>```
````

Comment: Do you have any kind of `WebView` inside code?

Comment: Yes, I do. There are place where dynamic content is displayed. This issue started happening only after updating Xamarin version (VS For mac) and Packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" on you AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Your AndroidManifest.xml look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.dww.drmanar">
   <application
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       tools:targetApi="m">
       <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: So that problem seems to go away, but on  Appcenter build, another problem is appearing, which does not happen on local machine. :```Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /Users/runner/runners/2.161.1/work/1/s/src/<project>obj/Release/android/src/com/google/android/gms/maps/R.java ```

Comment: is your appcenters android sdk up to date?

Comment: Oh yeah, targeting everything latest. It appears that using MonoDroid 6.4 seems to cause this issue and not 6.0.

Comment: ah hummm sounds interesting. But is it fixed?

Comment: So, android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" seems to fix the issue, but now the build process is crapping at this section: ```<GenerateLibraryResources....>```

Comment: Updating the platform and tools in Android SDK manager resolved this issue for me.

Comment: @zyzzyxx - did you delete  `bin` and `obj` folders?  To make sure project is truly cleaned.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes, I did. Also, I have noticed that, with newer version of Xamarin.build packages, if the nuget package versions are different across the assembly, I'm getting these errors. So, making them uniform seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 14):

For me, simply restarting the visual studio fixed this issue.

Comment: I got this issue when upgrading xamarin.build.download from 0.4.11 to 0.10.0. Also some other packages, but nothing worked until made sure all dependent projects were on the same version of xamarin.build.download (I missed one) and I restarted VS a few times in the process

Comment: I restarted VS, cleaned the solution then built it. Errors were gone.

Answer (score 4):

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` did not fix it for me.

I left that attribute in, because it might be enough in the future.

What fixed it was *downgrading* `Xamarin.Build.Download nuget` from `0.7.1` to `0.4.12-preview3`. `0.4.11` also worked - that was what I was using prior to today, when I updated all nugets.

I also tried `0.7.0` and `0.5.0-rc1`. Both had same problem as `0.7.1`.

---

All my Android SDKs and Tools are up-to-date.
Targeting Android 9.0 Pie (API 28), minimum (25), launching to an emulator running Oreo 8.1 (27).

(iOS builds and run successfully with `Xamarin.Build.Download` 0.7.1; the problem only happened on Android.)

Comment: It actually happened for me on iOS as well. 0.4.1 worked fined, but later versions were giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xamarin.Build.Download version 0.8.0 and apparently for me the issue was that the shared code project didn't have a reference to the package, it happens in both, android and iOS, installing the package in the three projects apparently solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case this error was hiding another error behind. Using VS2017 V15.9.12, and i was juggling between 2 VS windows with 2 open Xamarin Android projects that had some library projects in common. Restarting the PC fixed the issue.