# The "XamarinDownloadArchives" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am getting two error while Compiling Xamarin.iOS application on Visual Studio Mac (Version 8.4.3 (build 12)).

Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991640

Xamarin.Build.Download.0.9.0

Error :

1.packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.9.0/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(3,3): 
Error MSB4063: The "XamarinDownloadArchives" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  (MSB4063)

**2.**packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.9.0/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(4,4): 
Error MSB4064: The "AllowUnsecureUrls" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. (MSB4064)

Comment: update Xamarin.Forms to 4.5 and try again.

Comment: when did this error appear?

Comment: I have updated package but no luck..:(

Comment: First of all, uninstall this nugetpackages, close your VS, open your project folder, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, reinstall this nuget packages in your application. If this issue is disappear, if it still existed, please try to reback `Xamarin.Build.Download.` to 0.4.1, it was tested worked in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202701/10627299

Answer (score 14):

As suggested byb an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202701/10627299, restarting the visual studio fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to Xamarin.Build.Download versions mismatch: some projects used 0.10.0 and some others used older 0.4.1 which caused the old nuget's msbuild task to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I got this after I paired my Mac. I did a Clean and a Rebuild on the Android Project and it worked for me again.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading Xamarin.Build.Download on Nuget, in my case using 0.8.0 worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I changed the Android Project compiler setting -
Debug Information from 'Full' to 'None'.

Although it doesn't allow breakpoints in Android project when done so, I'm at least able to compile both iOS & Android projects without any issue.

When I'm dedicatedly working on the Android project, I change the setting back to 'Full' and then revert it to 'None' once done.